# NodeJS package LIKE pythons PIL

Tags: python, node.js, png, python-imaging-library, bmp

I'm competing in Ludum Dare 44, and have hit my first big snag.

I've written a Node application (server side) running in terminal. I want to export a PNG map that I created from Perlin Noise, to fill an array of 1024*1024 size.

My problem is that I can't find anything on NPM that can create an image from scratch, on the terminal. I don't want to write it to a canvas, or something else like that. I specifically want to write it to a file.

Does anyone have any knowledge of a package that:

1. can create an image (PNG) in the same way that Pythons PIL (Python Image Library) can just address an image as an array.
2. If this does not exist, can anyone give me guidance on creating an image from scratch?  I believe BMP is quite easy, it's a header, with an array of pixels from left to right if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with Processing, you could use the [p5.js](http://p5js.org) library to create the image and then save it to the filesystem? You just wouldn't add it to a canvas in the DOM.

Comment: A worthy thought, unfortunately I'm not familiar.  If I get past the bulk of other work and have the time to learn before the compo ends, I'll investigate it more deeply.  Thank you :)